# Javascript function solution

Tags: javascript

I need to implement the **solution** function such as running the following line:

```
console.log(solution('Hello You !'))
```

gives the following output (one word per line):

**Hello**

**You**

**!**

The input parameter is always a non-null character string.
So i did that code:

```js
function solution(input){
     
     arr=input.split(" ");
    for(var i=0;i<arr.length;i++) {
        console.log(arr[i]);
    }

}
input="Hello You !";
console.log(solution('Hello You !'));
```

But when i run it , i get the result:

**Hello**

**You**

**!**

**undefined**

Why the result of my code snippet displays "**undefined**"?

What is that "**undefined**"? how can i fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not returning anything, you have to return the `arr`

```js
function solution(input){
     
     arr=input.split(" ");
    for(var i=0;i<arr.length;i++) {
        console.log(arr[i]);
    }
    
    return arr;
}
```

When you call a function, the value will be its return value. If no return value is specified, a function returns undefined.

Comment: Doesn't solve the problem. Now instead of `undefined`, it will additionally print out the array.

Comment: True, but OP asked what is the undefined and how can he fix it, so seems to solve the problem in that regard.

Answer (score 3):

Because the return value of your function is `undefined`.

You're not only logging to the console from within the function, but you're also logging the return value of your function.

Instead of:

```
console.log(solution('Hello You !'));
```

Just do:

```
solution('Hello You !');
```

---

If your requirements dictate that you have to invoke the function with `console.log(solution('Hello You !'))`, you could consider splitting and joining:

```js
const solution = (input) => input.split(' ').join('\n');

console.log(solution('Hello You !'));
```

Or use a replacement:

```js
const solution = (input) => input.replaceAll(' ', '\n');

console.log(solution('Hello You !'));
```

Answer (score 0):

In your code, you are returning nothing (undefined) from the `solution` function so you are getting `undefined` at the end. I think a very succinct but still readable answer would be the following code if you are permitted to just invoke the `solution` function without surrounding it in `console.log`.

```js
        
        function solution(input){     
             input.split(" ").forEach(word=> console.log(word));   
        }
        
        solution('Hello You !')
```